# style-src blocks JavaScript editing Inline styles

Tags: javascript, html, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes'
```

```
function pureFadeOut(elem){
  var el = document.getElementById(elem);
  el.style.opacity = 1;

  (function fade() {
    if ((el.style.opacity -= .02) < 0) {
      el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
      setTimeout(() => {
      var theelement = document.querySelector('#cookieConsentContainer');
            if (theelement) {
            theelement.remove();
        };
      }, 1350);
  })();
};
```

```
<div class="cookieConsentContainer" id="cookieConsentContainer" style="opacity: 1; display: block;"></div>

<script src="purecookie.js"></script>
```

The CSP provided blocks inline styles, which I would like not to be blocked. Following from [other sources](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-style/), in the HTML section, the `style` attribute should be allowed due to the `'unsafe-hashes'`, it doesn't seem to work according to the console (Chrome).

```
purecookie.js:79 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ocbYmzLZH1xplQZkplgRzBKXmnx+nXhqw2fRcEogPQ4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

As I can't put what Chrome recommends me into a JavaScript file directly. I did put it on the `script` tag, but it returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#unsafe-hashes-usage, 'unsafe-hashes' is intended to allow some inline event handlers (attributes) to be allowed for legacy sites. You will need 'unsafe-inline' or rewriting the script code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 'unsafe-inline' * to style-src to get :
Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' *

This will enable inline execution however it's not recommended for security concern.

You can find useful information in this link: [CSP](https://web.dev/csp/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).